# select a id with variable in jquery onclick method

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I want to select id with variable count and pass each time new value of count. But it can't getting the id with count in this way. How's it is possible.

```
$(document).on('click','#remove-'+count,function (){
                    console.log(count);
                    if(count < 2) {
                        toastr.error('Cant Remove this','Error');
                    }else{
                        let id = $('#area-'+count).data('id');
                        let url = "{{route('admin_remove_area')}}";
                        let data = {
                            '_token' : '{{csrf_token()}}',
                            'id' : id
                        }
                        $.post(url,data,function(response){
                            if(response.status === 'success'){
                                remove_dynamic_field();
                            }else{
                                toastr.error(response.message);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
```

Comment: We need to see your html

Comment: Numbered ids always trigger a "code smell" warning for me... With that setup an _"attribute starts with"_ (`^=`) selector should work.

Comment: my jquery code to append the new option on click add.